# Change the Height of HeaderView inside tableviewSection with Animation + UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have an one Tableview. inside tableview at i insert a stack view which contain the `2 view(Blue and Gray)` with FillEqually. now i face the issue while hide a one view(Blue). the another view(Gray) take place of it and make it bigger. the height of `headerview` is must be change after hide another view. i have given `UITableView.automaticDimension`. Below is a sample code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblView.delegate = self
        tblView.dataSource = self
        tblView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView:headerView = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("headerView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? headerView)!

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.tblView.beginUpdates()
                headerView.view1.isHidden = true
                headerView.stackview.setNeedsLayout()
                headerView.stackview.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.view.setNeedsLayout()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.tblView.endUpdates()
            })

        }
         return headerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

The headerview is an xib which have below code

```
class headerView: UIView {
    //initWithFrame to init view from code
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackview: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    //initWithCode to init view from xib or storyboard
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    //common func to init our view
    private func setupView() {
        backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Constraint given in HeaderView.Xib

[image]

**What i want here.** for example the view1 height is 30, view2 have 30 then total height is 60 of stackview and headerview. so after hide a view1. the total height of headerview and stackview is 30 only.